# Why can't I send SOAP requests to Ebay finding API?

Tags: php, soap, ebay-api

This is my code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
//new instance of soapClient pointing to Ebay finding api
$client = new SoapClient("http://developer.ebay.com/webservices/finding/latest/FindingService.wsdl");

//attach required parameters to soap message header
$header_arr = array();
$header_arr[] = new SoapHeader("X-EBAY-SOA-MESSAGE-PROTOCOL", "SOAP11");
$header_arr[] = new SoapHeader("X-EBAY-SOA-SERVICE-NAME", "FindingService");
$header_arr[] = new SoapHeader("X-EBAY-SOA-OPERATION-NAME", "findItemsByKeywords");
$header_arr[] = new SoapHeader("X-EBAY-SOA-SERVICE-VERSION", "1.0.0");
$header_arr[] = new SoapHeader("X-EBAY-SOA-GLOBAL-ID", "EBAY-GB");
$header_arr[] = new SoapHeader("X-EBAY-SOA-SECURITY-APPNAME", "REMOVED");
$header_arr[] = new SoapHeader("X-EBAY-SOA-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT", "XML");
$header_arr[] = new SoapHeader("X-EBAY-SOA-MESSAGE-PROTOCOL", "XML");

$test = $client->__setSoapHeaders($header_arr);

$client->__setLocation("http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1"); //endpoint

$FindItemsByKeywordsRequest = array(
    "keywords" => "potter"
);

$result = $client->__soapCall("findItemsByKeywords", $FindItemsByKeywordsRequest);

//print_r($client->__getFunctions());
//print_r($client->__getTypes());
//print_r($result);
```

And this is the error I receive:

> Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [axis2ns2:Server] Missing SOA operation name header in C:\xampplite\htdocs\OOP\newfile.php:25 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampplite\htdocs\OOP\newfile.php(25): SoapClient->__soapCall('findItemsByKeyw...', Array) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampplite\htdocs\OOP\newfile.php on line 25

It doesn't make sense, I have already set the operation name in the header of the request...
Does anyone know what is wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [SoapHeader documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapheader.soapheader.php), you need to pass a namespace (or at least NULL) as the first parameter of the header construction call.

Answer (score 0):

Place the code in a try/catch and var_dump() the exception you're getting. That should give you more detail as to what is the problem.

Comment: It does not provide any additional useful info, just: "Missing SOA operation name header" even though I set the operation name header.
so frustrating

Answer (score 0):

I know this is REALLY old - but you need to specify the following HTTP headers (not soap headers - be aware of the distinction).

Here is an example that works for finding service:

CONTENT-TYPE:   SOAP12
X-EBAY-SOA-OPERATION-NAME:  findItemsByKeywords
X-EBAY-SOA-SECURITY-APPNAME:    YOUR-ebay-app-id